# android webview net::err_unknown_url_scheme :tel

Tags: android

```
package mockcall.mockcall;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
import com.mockcall.android.R;


/**
 * Created by fazzix on 8/4/2017.
 */


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  Snackbar snackbar;
  WebView webView;
  String url;

  private ProgressDialog progressx;
  private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
  Context context;
  String x = "x";
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    progressx = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressx.setMessage("Checking connection...  ");
    progressx.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id
      .a);
    snackbar = Snackbar
      .make(coordinatorLayout, "No internet connection! (Offline mode isn't supported.)", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
      .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
          intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
          startActivity(intent);
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

          bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
          mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
        }
      });
    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
      snackbar.show();
    }
    progressx.show();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);


    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1024 * 1024); // 5MB
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); // load online by default

    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //webPage.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + "crm.agile.agilecrm" + "/databases/");



    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


    webView.loadUrl("https://mockcall.com");
  }




  private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        snackbar.show();
      } else {
        view.loadUrl(url);

      }


      return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
      if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        snackbar.show();


      }
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      progressx.cancel();


    }

  }
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
      webView.goBack();
    } else {
      super.onBackPressed();
    }
  }
  private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
      if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        snackbar.show();


      } else {
        MainActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
      }
    }
  }

  public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progressx.setProgress(progress);
  }



  private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
  }

}
```

This is my Mainactivity can somebody please help me to solve the issue when i click on the phone number it gives me error "Error net::err_unknown_url_scheme tel:"
   ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍
   ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍
    ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍